# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY without google api

Tags: android, sqlite

Okay, I've been browsing but all I end up with is the api from google. I'm not using any api from google in my application..

I'm writing an application that uses an the sqlite browser and not any other reference yet. Any idea? I haven't started the application before so it's a very big try out right now.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="main.abvas"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OrderDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_order_details" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your manifest, notably the `<uses-library>` element inside of it.

Comment: updated, can it be because of the com.symbol.emdk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your project is requesting a firmware library:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk" />
```

The device or emulator you are testing your app on does not contain this library.

Your choices are:

1. Remove this library, if you are not actually using it
2. Only test your app on devices that have this library
3. Add `android:required="false"` to the `<uses-library>` element and detect at runtime if you have access to the library, probably by calling `Class.forName()` on some Java class that should be in the library

Comment: Currently works like a charm, thanks. Time to get my hands on that library if it's not located at the required device yet..

Comment: It's a library for Zebra devices which you can download from the Zebra Developer Portal https://developer.zebra.com/community/android/emdk

Comment: @Tosfera Hi, how did you managed to get it work? Also, are you testing it on Zebra device or native android device?

Comment: This has been so long ago but I was making the application for a scanning device, I had to install a specific package from that company onto the scanner to get it working. They had their own kernal version, including the firmware update with this library. If I wanted to test it on an emulator, I had to download their library and start an emulator with that package. Each and every device which was running the application had to get a firmware update. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @Tosfera I am working on EMDK now and I am seeing same issue. I am able to get it working using DataWedge but not with EMDK and I have no idea. Please help as I am kind of stuck on this since few days. This in on Mac so not sure if I have to do differently.