# How to Test EMDK functionality on traditional android Device?

Tags: java, android

So I've been stuck for a while, scratching my head around, I don't know how to test my application on Emulator or on my testing android device, when I try to run the application it gives an error on installation

> 09/02 14:17:01: Launching 'app' on Pixel API 24.
> Installation did not succeed.
> The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
>
> List of apks: [0]
> '/home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/projectName/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
> Installation failed due to: 'null' Retry

**Solutions Tried**

[Stackoverflow Link to the possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526564/install-failed-missing-shared-library-without-google-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an Intensive search and many failures, I came across a solution which is not a final solution but a workaround for testing EMDK application, during its development phases. It's hard for newbies, but it will make sense if you have prior knowledge of Instrumental Testing using JUNIT.

**Instrumented Testing**

```
//  Simulate a barcode being scanned
mockedInterface.AddScanData(“123456789”);
ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection = mockedInterface.ReportScan(success);
```

**Pass Test Data**

```
//  Trigger the data listener
activity.onData(scanDataCollection);
```

**Check credibility of data**

```
 //  Test that the correct data was scanned
onView(withId(R.id.textViewData)).check(matches(withText(”0123456789\n”)));
```

**Github link to sample Project:**
[Github](https://github.com/darryncampbell/Instrumented-EMDK-Barcode-Testing/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/darryncampbell/InstrumentedEMDKBarcodeTesting/com/symbol/emdk/barcode/test/EMDKBarcodeStub.java)

**Link to Original Source:**
[Original Source](https://darryncampbellblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/01/instrumented-testing-and-the-zebra-emdk-barcode-api/)